# Bash script to iterate record in file and extract value based on condition

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

Appreciate if any help for below query. Will require bash script. I am new to this scripting technology.

I have the below file at some location - say filename as MemberFile.txt.

```
#
[ID          ]  #1
[ADDRE1      ]  Address Line #1
[ADDRE2      ]  Mumbai City
[ADDRE3      ]  India
#
[ID          ]  #2
[ADDRE1      ]  House No 2
[ADDRE3      ]  Green Society
[ADDRE4      ]  Kolkatta
#
[ID          ]  #3
[ADDRE1      ]  Plot Num 77
[ADDRE2      ]  House No # [567]
[ADDRE3      ]  greener Apt
#
```

File can have millions of such records. I wanted to quickly iterate through each record and get and store value for `[ADDRE3      ]`. Also check if that record contains either of word 'society' or 'Num' (case insensitive). If yes, then get value of tag `[ID          ]` in that record.

Expected output is #2 and #3.

Please note that below one represents one record.

```
[ID          ]  #1
[ADDRE1      ]  Address Line #1
[ADDRE2      ]  Mumbai City
[ADDRE3      ]  India
```

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/\[ID /{ r=$3; c=3; next }c-- && $0~/society/{ print r }' MemberFile.txt
```

The output:

```
#2
#3
```

---

- `IGNORECASE=1` - set caseinsensitive comparison mode
- `/\[ID /{ r=$3; c=3; next }` - capturing `ID` record number `#<number>` (as the 3rd field)
- `c-- && $0~/society/` - check if any of the 3 following records contains `society` word

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
grep -iE '(^\[ADDRE3.*society|^\[ADDRE3.*no|^\[ADDRE3.*blabla)' -B 3 MemberFile.txt | grep "ID" | grep -o "#[0-9]*"
```

Written what is exactly happening:

So we are filtering caseinsensitive `-i` with regular expression `-E` on after every line that starts with "[ADDRE3" `^\[ADDRE3` with any amount of text inbetween `.*` until we hit our desired name `society` or `|` the other things.

If we get a hit we display the line + 3 lines `-B 3` above it.

Then we filter all lines for ID which we afterwards filter after the #Number which we only display `-o`

Search any ADDRE:

```
grep -iE '(^\[ADDRE.*society|^\[ADDRE.*no|^\[ADDRE.*blabla)' -B 3 MemberFile.txt | grep "ID" | grep -o "#[0-9]*"
```

Comment: I wanted to iterate records as well. Lets say I want to get ADDR3 value from each record. Society is one word. What if we want to check multiple words. Check if it contains either of 'society' or 'No'.

Comment: Adjusted it to be case insensitive and for more than one word.

Comment: Since you only want hits with [ADDRE3 we might need to adjust that a little more...

Comment: hits can be anywhere in the record and not with only tag [ADDR3. I want this tag irrespective of record contains hit or no.

Comment: Lets first check as how we can get each record. I mean get all the three records. My intention is iterate through each record. Get the value for tag '[ADDR3   ]'. Check if that whole record contain any of the field 'society' or 'num'. if yes then get value for tag [ID  ] of that record.

Comment: If you want to just check any address just remove the number from them I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '
   next unless /^#$/ && !$flag ... /^#$/ && $flag;
   $flag++,next if /^#$/ && !$flag;
   /^\[ID\h/ and $id = s/.*\h#/#/r,next;
   push @A, $_;
   if ( (/^#$/ && $flag) ) {
      print $id if join($/, splice(@A,0,@A)) =~ /(?:^|\h)(?i:society|num)(?:\h|$)/m;
      $flag = 0; undef $id; redo;
   }
' MemberFile.txt
```

#### Working

Each record starts with # (with flag OFF) and ends with # (flag ON).
The first action to take upon encountering a fresh record is to turn ON the flag.(much like you would turn on the lights when entering a room).

When meeting the ID line in a record, save it's value. For all other lines in the record, save each into the array `@A`.

Upon hitting the last line of the record (/#/ with flag ON), print the id
provided the array elements when strapped with newlines are known to contain words "society" or "num". Note that the `splice` empties the array.

We turn OFF the flag(as one should upon exiting a room) and `redo` rather than `next` since it's this same line we shall be cannibalizing for the beginning of the next record.

We pretty much use the same method using `sed` , but since it doesn't have arrays we make use of hold space for our storage purposes. Note that this code is POSIX compliant, with GNU `sed`-isms it could be condensed quite a bit.

```
sed -e '
   /^\[ID[[:blank:]]/,/^#$/!d
   H;/^\[ID[[:blank:]]/h;/^#$/!d
   g;y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
   /[[:blank:]]num$/ba
   /[[:blank:]]society$/ba
   /[[:blank:]]num\n/ba
   /[[:blank:]]society\n/ba
   /[[:blank:]]num[[:blank:]]/ba
   /[[:blank:]]society[[:blank:]]/ba
   d;:a
   s/\n.*//
   s/^\[id[[:blank:]].*#/#/
' MemberFile.txt
```

---

### Results

```
#2
#3
```